# use regex and grep to get all unique instances of pattern in a log file

Tags: regex, grep

I need to get a list of unique client computer names/ip addresses that are accessing a server from the access logs of the server.

The target log line looks like this:

```
2020-11-17 15:34:04.208 -0500 Information 94  XYZ-ASDF-FMP123  Client "%USERNAME% (QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]" opening database "databasename" as "username".
```

In this example, the string `(QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]` would be an example of a unique instance of a client computer/ip address.

So the result would be something like this:

```
(QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]
(QWER-L1234-W7) [11.22.333.55]
etc...
```

I tried this without success:

```
grep --only-matching '\(.+\) \[.+\]' | sort --unique Access.log
```

the matching fails and the entire log line is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note you are using a POSIX BRE regex flavor since you do not pass `-E`/`-r` nor `-P` options to change the regex flavor from the default one. `\(...\)` defines a capturing group in POSIX BRE. There are more issues here though.

You need to use

```sh
grep -o '([^()]*) \[[^][]*]' Access.log | sort -u
```

Note the location of the input file argument to `grep`.

The `([^()]*) \[[^][]*]` here is a POSIX BRE pattern that matches

- `(` - a literal `(` char (a `\(` is the start of a capturing group)
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a literal `)` char (a `\)` is the end of a capturing group)
- - a space
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]`  - a `]` char.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/DfbyyP):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='2020-11-17 15:34:04.208 -0500 Information 94  XYZ-ASDF-FMP123  Client "%USERNAME% (QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]" opening database "databasename" as "username".'
grep -o '([^()]*) \[[^][]*]' <<< "$s" | sort -u
# => (QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --only-matching '\(.+\) \[.+\]' file.log
```

This is failing because you are not using ERE (extended regex or `-E`) in `grep` and `+` is not escaped. So for your case following may work:

```
grep -E --only-matching '\(.+\) \[.+\]' file.log
```

However this regex is problematic because `.+` will match 1+ of any character before matching closing `)` and closing `]`. If you have `(...) [...]` substring in your log like this:

```sh
2020-11-17 15:34:04.208 -0500 Information 94  XYZ-ASDF-FMP123  Client "%USERNAME% (QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]" opening database "databasename" as "username".
2020-11-17 15:34:04.208 -0500 Information 94  XYZ-ASDF-FMP123  Client "%USERNAME% (QWER-L1212-W6) [21.22.333.33]" opening database "databasename" as "username" (QWER-L1234-W7) [11.22.333.55]
```

**Then you will get incorrect results.** Incorrect results will also show up with the pattern as `'([^()]*) \[[^][]*]'`.

Since you are using `access.log` where format and positions of fields are fixed it is much safer and efficient to use `awk` for this extraction like this:

```sh
awk -F '"' '{sub(/^[^ ]* /, "", $2); print $2}' file.log

(QWER-L1212-W6) [11.22.333.44]
(QWER-L1212-W6) [21.22.333.33]
```